# CosmosDB UDF to return a date 5 days from now

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying tow rite a small UDF for testing purposes that will return todays date plus 5 days, I need this in order to test a small query that compares a range of dates to ensure a document should be included

The document looks like this

```
{
    "id": "12345",
    "brand": "XXX",
    "PromotionName": "Test Promo 1",
    "PromotionType": "Deal",
    "PromotionSticker": "Sticker 1",
    "StartDate": "2020-05-15T00:00:00.1212122Z",
    "EndDate": "2020-05-30T00:00:00.1212122Z",
    "Variants": [
        "0628462008001",
        "0628462008002",
        "0644324003002"
    ],
    "Stores": [
        "SE0623"
    ],
    "Users": [
        "ALL"
    ],
    "DiscountInPercent": "30",
    "RedPriceStores": null,
    "CreatedDate": "20200515",
    "CreatedBy": "SLAPI Promotions API ClientId: 123",
    "UpdatedDate": null,
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "Consumer": "Storelens_V2",
    "_rid": "HwVmAIFaOoEBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/HwVmAA==/colls/HwVmAIFaOoE=/docs/HwVmAIFaOoEBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"1100092f-0000-0c00-0000-5ebe07280000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1589511976
}
```

So I wrote a small query like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM c
WHERE ARRAYCONTAINS(c.Variants, '0628462008001')
AND ARRAYCONTAINS(c.Stores, 'SE0623')
AND c.StartDate <= (SELECT GetCurrentDateTime())
AND c.EndDate >= (SELECT udf.todaysDatePlus5())
```

My idea was that I could use the UDF to test the validity of my query as it would return a date in the future for testing purposes

My UDF is small as follows

```
function todaysDatePlus5(){
    var date = new Date();
    var a = date.setDays(+5);
    return a;
}
```

but when I run this I get an error message like this

```
Failed to query item for container promotions: {"code":400,"body":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'setDays'\\r\\nStack trace: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'setDays'\\n   at todaysDatePlus5 (todaysDatePlus5.js:3:5)\\n   at __docDbMain (todaysDatePlus5.js:8:5)\\n   at Global code (todaysDatePlus5.js:1:2)\"]}\r\nActivityId: 9a98388f-a574-4b5e-a15c-6e48755b23b4, Request URI: /apps/ebe17a4f-1254-45f9-be9c-b6b25f776dc2/services/0d1b0155-67dd-416e-bdfa-13801f1e8a6e/partitions/886be96a-2c7f-4b54-9681-e026cd2ca707/replicas/132338964530434550p/, RequestStats: \r\nRequestStartTime: 2020-05-15T03:23:07.5903385Z, RequestEndTime: 2020-05-15T03:23:07.5903385Z,  Number of regions attempted:1\r\nResponseTime: 2020-05-15T03:23:07.5903385Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-northeurope1-fd1.documents.azure.com:14006/apps/ebe17a4f-1254-45f9-be9c-b6b25f776dc2/services/0d1b0155-67dd-416e-bdfa-13801f1e8a6e/partitions/886be96a-2c7f-4b54-9681-e026cd2ca707/replicas/132338964530434550p/, LSN: 10, GlobalCommittedLsn: 10, PartitionKeyRangeId: 0, IsValid: True, StatusCode: 400, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 1, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#10, UsingLocalLSN: True, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Query\r\n, SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0"},"headers":{"x-ms-request-charge":1,"x-ms-documentdb-query-metrics":{}},"activityId":"9a98388f-a574-4b5e-a15c-6e48755b23b4"}
```

If I try the UDF by itself like this

```
select udf.todaysDatePlus5()
```

I am getting the same error message

What am I doing wrong here? its such a simple UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like following:

```
function todaysDatePlus5(){
    var date = new Date();
    var a = date.setDate(date.getDate()+5);
    return new Date(a);
}
```